# CZ characters from keyboard Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am working on a word game that can take input from the keyboard. Below is the code to detect the key

```
foreach(KeyCode kcode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
{
    if (Input.GetKey(kcode))
        Debug.Log("KeyCode down: " + kcode);
}
```

But this code is not taking input CZ language special characters (ě š č ř ž ý á í é ). I already switched my keyboard to the CZECH version.

Your guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use Input.GetKey for keyboard input. It is meant for reading game controls which don't change when you change the input language. To read text, use [Input.inputString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Since this looks like this, I assume that you "type" special characters like so "AltGr + 2" to get ě

So to get this key you need to add those two keys

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.AltGr) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha2))
    Debug.Log("KeyCode down: AltGr & 2 equals ě");
```

You need to "hardcode" for each letter unique configuration to get all special characters

**EDIT**

To use it like that [Link from a comment](https://gate2home.com/Czech-Keyboard) - as far as Unity is considered, those buttons should be mapped to numeric alpha keys.

So using `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha2)` is equal to ě - but you need to write your own handler for that.

Comment: No, I'm typing directly from the CHECH keyboard just by pressing a key. Like in the link. https://gate2home.com/Czech-Keyboard

Comment: @ZeeshanArif Please see the edit I made, I hope this helps